# Is it possible to use dependency properties on POCOs?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I don't know too much about dependency properties, except that their values can be sourced from parent and above elements when not provided in specific elements.

I have a case where I have password controls defined for all employees, and then for individual employees. I would like some automated way of using the parent collection parameters when individual employee parameters are not supplied, and then, e.g. these properties for an employee applying to for all visitors for an employee, except where certain properties overridden for particular visitors.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. Can you be more elaborative about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

[Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> DependencyObject defines the base class that can register and own a dependency property.

For objects that cannot derive from Dependency Object, you have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.